# VSCode LiveServer Reloading Issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, liveserver

The LiveServer in my VSCode is somehow not working correctly and stably, I have to manually refresh. I can say that I tried all the solutions I found, but I could not get a definite result. Below I am sharing the settings.json, I hope I can find a solution with your help.

```
{
"typescript.validate.enable": false,
"javascript.validate.enable": false,
"workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro",
"liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
"liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
"editor.wordWrap": "on",
"files.exclude": {
    "**/.git": false
},
"liveServer.settings.ChromeDebuggingAttachment": false,
"liveServer.settings.useWebExt": false,
"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
"liveServer.settings.port": 0,
"window.zoomLevel": 0,
"workbench.startupEditor": "none",
"emmet.useInlineCompletions": true,
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
},
"[css]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.css-language-features"
},
"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
}
```

Besides this problem, I also started getting Uncaught Error in Console, it doesn't block the stream, but it's annoying to just sit there. The error I get is as follows:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: "undefined" is not valid JSON
at A (content.js:1:9544)

Even if this 2nd problem is not solved, I will be very happy if I can find a solution for LiveServer.

Answer (score 4):

It could be caused by a browser plugin cause. I had this problem too, but after uninstall this plugin, it was fixed:

[image]